# Möbius transformation in the complex plane.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

Assume that $U$ be a line in the complex plane.

And assume a Möbius transformation $\phi $ sends $ U $ again to a line.

How can I classify all such $\phi$?

---

I want to write my ideas. But, I cannot do anything. Please explain. I saw this question in a textbook as an exercise. This seems so interesting to me. I just want to learn this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, every Möbius transformation [maps generalized circles to generalized circles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobius_transformation#Preservation_of_angles_and_generalized_circles). In particular, the line $U$ will be sent to either a line or a circle, and it will be sent to a line if and only if some point on the line is sent to the point at infinity. There are two possibilities, then, for what form such a transformation will have.

**Option 1**: If the point at infinity (which one can consider as a point on every line in the plane) is sent to the point at infinity, then we are dealing with a map of the form $\phi(z)=\zeta z+\xi,$ where $\zeta,\xi$ are complex constants with $\zeta\ne 0.$

**Option 2**: If some other point on the line $U$ is sent to the point at infinity (say the point $z_0$), then we are dealing with a map of the form $$\phi(z)=\frac{\alpha z+\beta}{z-z_0},$$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are complex constants such that $\alpha z_0+\beta\ne 0.$

---

Here is the outline of a proof that the above classification covers all such $\phi,$ using results from the link you posted:

To begin with, we know we are dealing with Möbius transformations, which are of the form $$\phi(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d},$$ where $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb C$ such that $ad-bc\ne0.$ By Theorem 3.4, we know that any such transformation will map our line $U$ into either a circle or a line. We can actually say more than Theorem 3.4 says. If we consider the point at infinity to be a point on every line, then we can (and should) show that Möbius transformations map circles and lines into *and onto* circles and lines. To prove this, we can use Lemma 3.2 (in particular, the formula for the inverse of a Möbius transformation), together with the definitions of arithmetic in $\hat{\Bbb C}=\Bbb C\cup\{\infty\}.$

If $\phi(z)=\zeta z+\xi$ for some $\zeta,\xi\in\Bbb C$ with $\zeta\ne0,$ then we can easily write $$\phi(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$ with $a=\zeta,b=\xi,c=0,d=1,$ so that $ad-bc=\zeta\ne0$ (so we are dealing with a Möbius transformation), and since $c=0,$ then $\phi(\infty)=\infty$ by Lemma 3.8. Since there are points on $U$ arbitrarily far from the origin, then it can (and should) be shown that we can find $z\in U$ with $z\ne\infty$ such that $|\phi(z)|$ is as large as we like, meaning that $\phi(U)$ is not bounded, so cannot be a circle, and so must be a line. Hence, for all nonzero $\zeta\in\Bbb C$ and all $\xi\in\Bbb C,$ the transformation $\phi(z)=\zeta z+\xi$ is a Möbius transformation that will map the line $U$ to a line.

If $\phi(z)=\dfrac{\alpha z+\beta}{z-z_0}$ for some $z_0\in U,$ $z_0\ne\infty,$ and so $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb C$ with $\alpha z_0+\beta\ne 0,$ then we have $$\phi(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$ with $a=\alpha,b=\beta,c=1,d=-z_0,$ so $ad-bc=-\alpha z_0-\beta=-(\alpha z_0+\beta)\ne0$ (so we are dealing with a Möbius transformation), and since $c\ne 0,$ then $\phi(z_0)=\phi(-\frac dc)=\infty$ by Lemma 3.8. Since there are points on $U$ arbitrarily close to $z_0,$ then it can (and should) be shown that we can find $z\in U$ with $z\ne z_0$ such that $|\phi(z)|$ is as large as we like. By the same sort of reasoning as above, we see that for all $z_0\in U$ with $z_0\ne\infty$ and for all $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb C$ such that $\alpha z_0+\beta\ne 0,$ the transformation $\phi=\dfrac{\alpha z+\beta}{z-z_0}$ is a Möbius transformation that will map the line $U$ to a line.

All that is left is to show that the *only* Möbius transformations that will map the line $U$ to a line are those which can be written in the forms described above. So, we start with a general Möbius transformation $$\phi(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$$ (where $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb C$ such that $ad-bc\ne 0$) and suppose that $\phi(U)$ is a line. Since $\infty\in\phi(U),$ then one of the following must be true:

- There is some $z_0\in U$ with $z_0\ne\infty$ such that $\phi(z_0)=\infty.$
- $\phi(\infty)=\infty.$

In the first case, note that we *cannot* have $c=0,$ for if so, then since $ad-bc\ne 0,$ we have $d\ne 0,$ so that $\phi(z_0)=\frac{az_0+b}d\in\Bbb C,$ contradicting our assumption that $\phi(z_0)=\infty.$ Since $c\ne 0,$ let $\alpha=\frac ac,\beta=\frac bc,$ so $\alpha,\beta\in\Bbb C,$ and dividing numerator and denominator by $c,$ we can rewrite $$\phi(z)=\cfrac{\alpha z+\beta}{z+\frac dc}.$$ Now, $$\infty=\phi(z_0)=\cfrac{\alpha z_0+\beta}{z_0+\frac dc},$$ so we *must* have $z_0+\frac dc=0,$ as otherwise $\phi(z_0)\in\Bbb C.$ Thus, $\frac dc=-z_0,$ so that $$\phi(z)=\frac{\alpha z+\beta}{z-z_0},$$ and $$\alpha z_0+\beta=-\frac{ad}{c^2}+\frac bc=-\frac{ad-bc}{c^2}\ne 0.$$

In the second case, we *must* have $c=0,$ as otherwise, we have by Lemma 3.8 that $\phi(\infty)=\frac ac\in\Bbb C.$ Hence, since $ad=ad-bc\ne 0,$ we can conclude that $a,d\ne 0,$ so letting $\zeta=\frac ad$ and $\xi=\frac bd,$ we have that $\zeta,\xi\in\Bbb C$ with $\zeta\ne 0,$ and we can show that $\phi(z)=\zeta z+\xi.$